# How to make a REST call from Spring MVC Controller and return the response as it is

Tags: json, spring-mvc, resttemplate

I am trying to make a webservice call from my Spring MVC controller using RestTemplate,  I was wondering if there is a way to return the response as it is without unmarshaling to a Java object.

For example like in play framework,

`HttpResponse res = WS.url(url).get();
renderJSON(res.getString()); // or res.getJson()`

Most of my responses would be JSON or very rare case it might be a String.

Comment: if the client is returning string  as a response of a webservice, then there is no need of unmarhsalling. you can pass the string as is.

Comment: Santosh as I mentioned most of the time its JSON.  I don't want to have the POJOs in my application, I just need to forward the response back. Basically I was trying to see if there are equivalent option like play framework has.

Comment: what we used to do is, call a webservice get a json response, set the response in the sring mvc model to be used by client(ui) side. On the client side we have angular js which consumes this feed as is.

Comment: Could you please share that code?  Guess it would work for me too.  I use JQuery instead of Angular.

Comment: added the code to the answer, hope that will work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's some code snippet;

## ## JAVA Code

```
@Autowired
RestOperations operations;

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index( @PathVariable("id") String id, Model model) {

    //a) Call webservice using restemplate or using any other method
    //b) get the data from service
    //c) set data in modal

    String jsonFeed = operations.getForObject("URL", String.class);
    model.addAttribute("jsonFeed", jsonFeed);
}
```

### ## JSP CODE

```
// fetch the jsonFeed variable set in the modal attribute and set it into a java script variable and use the way u want.

<script type="text/javascript">
       var jsonObjToUse = jQuery.parseJSON(${jsonFeed})
 </script>
```

Comment: What I missed was the JQuery.parseJSON part.  Thanks for sharing the code.